# How do I refresh the page request in Imacros (Let it reload itself by code)

Tags: imacros

How do I refresh the page request in I macros (Let it reload itself by code)

I'd rather not use Response.Redirect() because I don't know if the page I will be on, as it's inside a user control inside a webpart inside sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
REFRESH
```

This is the code you are looking for.

Comment: I Know this  "refresh"

but I would like to refresh this request

to enable this  , without refresh fully


#ContentBody_lblSelectGame.error
#ContentBody_hdnAnswerId #ContentBody_txtcontrolCorrectData #ContentBody_txtcontrolMemberAnswerData #ContentBody_imgSubmit.aspNetDisabled.GameSubmitDisable
#ContentBody_ImgBtnLikeCount.aspNetDisabled

Comment: Try about:config in FireFox.

Comment: Thank you but I don't know how to "Enable "

Please tell me the "preference Name"

Comment: I don't know either. Search on the net.

Comment: Please help me , you can give me hint to search